# How to get an image behind a navigation bar

Tags: html, css, navigation

Kinda new to HTML, want to edit my navigation bar so that it has an image behind it and the nav bar sits at the bottom of the image.  How do I do this?

After looking at a few forum posts, this is what I tried:

```css
#cover {
background-image: url("Images\FB Cover.png");
}
```

```html
<div id="cover">

<div>
<nav>
<li><a href="Index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="About.html">About DRC</a></li>
<li><a href="Products.html">Our Products</a></li>
<li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</nav>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: @BishalSapkota Just added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to place image as background of DOM element you can use, background-image css property.
For example
        background-image: url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/87646/horsehead-nebula-dark-nebula-constellation-orion-87646.jpeg');

W3School has great documentation about css properties.
[here is the link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp)

Comment: This article helped, and I noticed that my image url in the CSS was not working, but how do I get the nav bar at the bottom of the image?

Comment: you could set style position:absolute; for your nav element when you want your element to be floating around over the other element. then you could use top, bottom, left, right to position x,y https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Answer (score 1):

```css
#cover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/800/600) no-repeat 50% 50% / cover;
}
menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
}
a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="cover">
  <menu>
    <li><a href="Index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="About.html">About DRC</a></li>
    <li><a href="Products.html">Our Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </menu>
<div>
```

simple example